# Plotting a part of curves (with possible solution as an attempt)

Tags: algebra-precalculus, recreational-mathematics, graphing-functions

*I may mess up with this question!*

**I plotted them using http://www.desmos.com/calculator**

> How to plot only a part of some curves?

**For example:**

Plot of $y=x^2$:

[image: 1]

> But if i want to plot the curve from $x=1$ to $x=2$ which will look something like:
>
> [image: 2]
>
> How to achieve it?

---

**My attempt:**

I can only do $[n,\infty)$, that is starting from $x=n$ but ending up in $\infty$. [*first limitation*]

Lets take a function say $f(x)=x$...

So suppose if i want to plot it from $x=3$...what i do is plot

$y=({\sqrt{x-3}})^2 + 3$

thus giving me :

[image: 3]

But it also does not work on even degree equation like $y=x^2$ which gives: [*second limitation*]

($y=({\sqrt{x^2-3}})^2 + 3$ )

[image: 4]

And also does not work with curves like $\sin{x}$ as using $y=({\sqrt{f(x)-n}})^2 + n$ (as i have been using) makes the values *non-real* if $n\geq 1$. [*third limitation*]

---

**My 2nd attempt**:

> I plotted $y=x^2+0{\sqrt{x-1}}^2+0{\sqrt{3-x}}^2$ to get :
>
> [image: 5]

which is exactly what i want but i guess the method is a little crude.

> Hence final method : $y=f(x)+0{\sqrt{x-a}}^2+0{\sqrt{b-x}}^2$ ... am i right?

Comment: The method of restricting the domain depends on your particular software. What do you use: TI-84 Plus, TI-Nspire, Geogebra, or other?

Comment: @RoryDaulton I want to restrict the domain using modified equations and not graphing calculators...

Comment: Do you mean using standard math notation? Many of your examples seem to use some kind of graphing software.

Comment: @RoryDaulton No ... i mean only using math...no manual domain input...like if you input > Plot ${\sqrt{x-3}}^2+3$ in desmos.com/calculator it will give just a straight line starting from $x=3$...I did not add any domain info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rory's suggestion is quite good, and it should work for Desmos. But apparently what you want is to stealthily include domain information; that's what it will boil down to, as we'll see.

To this end, you can cook up auxiliary "characteristic functions" that are $1$ at least on the domain you want, and $0$ certain places where you don't want to plot the function.

Thus, we'll let $$\ell_b(x) = \frac{1}{2(x - b)}\bigg(x - b - \lvert x - b\rvert\bigg) = \begin{cases}1, &x < b\\0, &x > b\end{cases}$$

so that $\ell_a(x)$ encodes whether $x \in (-\infty, a)$; that is, whether $x$ is to the $\ell$eft of $a$. Note that $\ell_a(a)$ is **not** defined (and I don't particularly care to find a way to make it either $1$ or $0$) at $x = b$.

Now, given any function $f(x)$, if you plot $\dfrac{f(x)}{\ell_b(x)}$, you'll get the graph of $f$ only for $x < b$.

You can do something analogous to define a characteristic function for the right-opening ray $(a, \infty)$, defining

$$r_a(x) = \frac{1}{2(a - x)}\bigg(a - x - \lvert a - x \rvert\bigg) = \begin{cases}0, &x < a\\1, &x > a\end{cases},$$

again noting that $r_b(x)$ is **not** defined for $x = a$.

Now, if you want to plot the function $f(x)$ for $a < x < b$, this is exactly

$$\frac{f(x)}{2}\bigg(\frac{1}{\ell_b(x)}+\frac{1}{r_a(x)}\bigg),$$

provided $a < b$.

So, it's really just sneakily including domain information, but if it's what you want to do, you can. Things are trickier to define a function on a union of intervals like $(-\infty, a) \cup (b, \infty)$, so I'll let you think about that, if you want. The key is just to figure out a way to divide by $0$ outside of your desired domain, and divide by $1$ on the desired domain (while rescaling, if you need to use a sum).

Comment: Yeah it works!!! But what about my "2nd attempt" (in the question)?

Comment: Your second attempt also works if you just care about the real value of the function. It's another way to make the function undefined (well, in your case, complex-valued) at the places you don't want, yet leave the parts you *do* want unaffected. It's going to be cumbersome to trick calculators (compared to just specifying the domain), no matter what you cook up.

Answer (score 3):

The method of restricting the domain depends on your particular software. Here are some examples. Let's graph $y=x^2$ for $0\le x\le 1$.

**TI-84 Plus (or similar):**

$$y1(x)=x^2/(x\ge 0)/(x\le 1)$$

**TI-Nspire**:

$$f1(x)=x^2\mid 0\le x\le 1$$

**Geogebra:**

$$f(x)=\operatorname{If}[0<=x<=1,x^2]$$

**Standard math notation:**
$$y=x^2\mid _{0\le x\le 1}$$
or
$$y=x^2,\quad\text{for $0\le x\le 1$}$$

**Plotting by hand:**

Just draw the parts you want and leave out the rest.

**Tricky function definition:**

$$y=x^2+0\cdot\left(\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{1-x}\right)$$

This method would work in any system that does not "optimize", which leaves out optimizing compilers for computer languages. You could call this a purely mathematical approach that also works in most technology. I just did a quick check on the TI-Nspire, Geogebra, and Desmos, and this works for all of them. A slight adaptation will make this work for a domain other than a closed interval.

These methods other than the last are all more standard, straightforward, understandable, and modifiable than the complicated formulas you are trying to use. Well, I suppose you could dispute the "standard" part, since I did them differently for different technologies.

Comment: I guess you did not read my question properly!

Comment: @NeilRoy: I did read it properly. I was just trying to get you to think differently about the problem and to use a different approach. I added another section to my answer that does use your approach.

Comment: Haha...but i actually want a purely mathematical approach! But yeah thanks for Tricky function def.

Comment: @NeilRoy: That I do not understand. What about my "standard math notation" or "tricky function definition" is not purely mathematical? And you are welcome!

Comment: I actually did not see your edited post! My bad

Answer (score 0):

Let $f$ be a function and $[a,b]$ be the domain in which you want to plot the function.

In most programming languages with [*type conversion*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_conversion) between booleans and numbers you could define the desired function as `f_restricted(x) = f(x)*(x >= a && x <= b)`,since `(x >= a && x <= b)` will be converted to `0` or `1` if it is evaluated to be true or false respectively.

Comment: No i want to do it mathematically using purely functions as in pjs36's answer